# Virtualizing/Paging Data in ObservableCollection bound to ItemsControl in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, observablecollection, virtualization

How can we Visualize data in an ObservableCollection or List which is set as ItemSource of ItemsControl?
We are using ItemsControl within a ScrollViewer to make a custom collections control, due to some technical reasons(Design Constraints), we can not use ListView, or GridView controls which supports VirtualizingStackPanel and Data Virtualization through ISupportIncremental, so we must use ItemsControl within a ScrollViewer. 
So how can our ScrollViewer control notify the bound observable collection that scrolling has come to an end and load more data into the ObservableCollection, 
I found some information on **Random access data virtualization** but not sure how would i implement that in my WinRT, C# Custom Control project, and sample codes would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing a custom list control (which you are if you're not using `ListView`, `GridView` or `ListBox`) then the `ScrollViewer` would need to be a part of its template, so you can listen to its `ViewChanging` and `ViewChanged` events that have [`IsInertial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewerviewchangingeventargs.isinertial.aspx) and [`IsIndeterminate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewerviewchangedeventargs.isintermediate.aspx) properties which you could use to see if scrolling has stopped and you could possibly use these to decide whether you have time to get more data or just put some placeholder values in the items source. You would also likely have an items source property and since you want to do your own virtualization - you don't really need to care about `ISupportIncremental` although you could use it as a (hopefully) good example. You get to implement your own virtualizing panel and the source list. Your view change events from the `ScrollViewer` and the layout of your panel would drive what gets loaded from the items source.

As for sample code - I haven't seen any, but would love to see some as well!

Comment: Is there a way to render the XAML in parts? like we render first 20 rows first and than as we scroll down, we render more

Comment: Yes and you do it by not having these elements that are outside of the view port at all. Rendering them isn't the biggest problem but having thousands of UI elements to do layout on will choke any CPU. That's why you use virtualization to mitigate that.

Comment: @FilipSkakun How would I implement UI virtualization on a custom items panel? Virtualization is lost as soon as I replace default virtualizing panels with my panel. Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819968/implement-ui-virtualization-in-custom-itemspanel/36845873#36845873