# Implement UI virtualization in custom ItemsPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

My goal is to display some layout like the official [Android Imgur app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imgur.mobile) where items have fixed width but variable height. I already have a custom panel with a `GridView`. It works. However, it breaks a couple of things:

1. I don't get UI virtualization. This is a big performance bottleneck when lots of images need to be rendered.
2. Since virtualization is gone, incremental loading isn't supported either.

I've searched around a lot, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to implement virtualization. So, I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it even possible to get virtualization with custom panel? How?
2. Is it possible to use one of the existing panels (`VirtualizedStackPanel` for example) to get the layout I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get virtualization on custom panels.
The last time I needed custom, virtualized panel was in a prototype of what you see in the Windows Photos app, where I've done all virtualization from scratch. I see two options for you then:

1. Implement virtualization yourself - put a panel (`Canvas` works great, but you can use a custom panel too) in a `ScrollViewer`, create some containers to fill a few screens worth of items and as you scroll - rearrange the containers and their content to always have some items in the realization window. It's fun and you can get amazing performance, especially if you pre-calculate and cache the layout of items on a background thread. You might need to put some effort into handling focus, keyboard input (you should probably always keep the focused container realized regardless of window position) or possibly accessibility, but it's going to be worth it.
2. Use your custom panel in a regular `ListView`, but instead of altering the `ListView.ItemsPanel` - leave it as default (`ItemsStackPanel`) and put your custom layout panel inside of the item template and have tall, but distinct rows of these panels. This means that your layout won't be jagged everywhere - items will need to align with the `ListViewItems` somewhere, but it's somewhat simpler to implement the basics. I think that's how the layout in the Photos app works. You will need to put a lot of effort to override the way a `ListView` handles input and displays selection visuals, but it might work for you. Remember that in this case your `ItemsSource` will need to have groups of items to perform custom layout on in each `ListViewItem`.

I'd choose the first option, but it's up to you. It's some more work initially, but overall it might end up being easier to get right, gives you freedom to lay things out without any rows and it will teach you something useful. The second option will just mean you'll have to mask built-in behaviors that you don't need anyway. I think the first option also separates the view layer better from the view model one as there is no layout-dependent grouping required in the `ItemsSource`, unless you implement some sort of view-layer aggregator `ItemsSource` that will process the items from the view model.

Read more about some theory and practice of virtualization in this great article:

[ListView basics and virtualization concepts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alainza/2014/09/03/listview-basics-and-virtualization-concepts/)

Comment: That's a great answer. I am naturally interested in solution 1. Do you have some code or articles that can shed some light on how to create, rearrange and destroy the containers?

Comment: I don't. I've only done it in an internal project. 1. Once you calculate the layout - you try to get containers from the cache for the items that should show up in the current realization window (your viewport and some extra space before and after the view port based on ScrollViewer properties), add them to your `Canvas` and set `Canvas.Top/Left` and `Width/Height` properties on the items based on precalculated layout.
2. If you don't have enough cached containers - you create new ones.
3. As your view changes - you remove from the panel and cache the containers that are outside of the window.

Comment: Getting closer. I was on a similar track. So more specific questions: 1. How (and where) do I obtain this realization window? 2. Where is virtualization exactly handled? In Arrange pass? 3. Again, how do I know what items need to be realized?

Comment: 1. You define it in your control. Whenever your items list changes, the size changes or your `ScrollViewer.ViewChanged` is raised - you need to calculate it based on your layout logic, `ScrollViewer.ViewPortHeight`, `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` and a parameter that specifies how much space above and below the viewport should be added to realization window. That could just be 3 viewport heights above and 3 below the viewport.
2. You handle virtualization - you add, remove and fill the containers as your user scrolls.
3. You realize the items that are in your window or have focus. You toss rest

Comment: Are you sure you can't add some sample code to the answer? I'm still having trouble understanding what code goes where. 1. Exactly where do I subscribe to the size and view change events? 2. I get that I handle the virtualization. But again, where does this code reside? 3. Again, how do I know what items are in the window?

Comment: I'll see if I can find some time to code up a sample as it'll take a while. I might do it tonight, but can't guarantee. 1. In your control constructor. 2. In your control. 3. As new items are added to the list or the width of your control changes - you'll recalculate the layout of all items in some list or dictionary. As you do that - you know exactly where they should be positioned in the vertically scrollable space. Your window might be `VerticalOffset`-3*`ViewPortHeight` to `VerticalOffset`+4*`ViewPortHeight`. If layout rects overlap the window - the items should be realized.

Comment: Have you had a chance to create an example? I'm still stumped a bit. Am I supposed to create entirely new control? Inherit from ListViewBase? I really feel like I'm asking very basic questions here. But I'm really confused about components and wiring.

Comment: For the record, in case you'd rather let the code talk, my custom panel can be found here: https://github.com/akshay2000/MonocleGiraffe/blob/master/MonocleGiraffe/MonocleGiraffe/Controls/ColumnPanel.cs Pull requests are welcome.

Comment: Sorry, I got really busy and never got back to you. I guess it's been a little while already so I'll get to it when I get to it...

Comment: @akshay2000 Did you get a sample? I want to make a custom virtualization too. I'm really appreciated to get your help.

Comment: @Land: [Here](https://github.com/akshay2000/MonocleGiraffe/blob/master/MonocleGiraffe/MonocleGiraffe/Controls/ColumnGridView.xaml.cs) is the currently working implementation. We can work something out for your case.