# Getting Large JSON Data Make Browser Rendering Issues

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have approx **100000 rows** in each of 4 database tables and using **web api async Action** to get the data through **ADO.NET Datasets**. I am using **2 drop downs and 2 grid views** to load **100000** entries into them. 
Following is one of the four controllers I am using to get the Data.

```
public class OrdersDCController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<int> GetOrdersDC()
    {
        return await DCOrderHelper.GetOrdersCount();
    }

    // GET api/Orders
    public async Task<List<OrderDTO>> GetOrdersDC(int offset, int fetchRecords)
    {
        return await DCOrderHelper.GetAllOrders(offset, fetchRecords);
    }
}
```

And the following ajax call is

```js
///The Button Click which makes an ajax call to Web API
            $("#btngetdata").click(function () {
                offset = 0;
                custRecordsRendered = 0;
                $.when(
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "/api/OrdersDC",
                    datatype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        totalRecords = data;
                        fetch = parseInt(totalRecords / 10);
                        $("#progressBar").progressbar(0);
                        //alert(fetch);
                        getDataAtOffset();
                    }
                })
                );
function getDataAtOffset() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "/api/OrdersDC?offset=" + offset * fetch + "&fetchRecords=" + fetch,
                        datatype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (customerData) {
                            var customers = [];
                            customers = getDataInArray(customerData); //Convert the JSON response into an Array
                            var custCount = customers.length;
                            for (var i = 0; i < custCount; i++) {
                                displayCustomerInformation($("#customerTemplate").render(customers[i]));
                                custRecordsRendered = custRecordsRendered + 1;
                            }
                            updateProgress();
                            if (offset * fetch < totalRecords) {
                                offset = offset + 1;
                                getDataAtOffset();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
function updateProgress() {
                var progress = $("#progressBar").progressbar("option", "value");
                if (progress < 10) {
                    //Increase the value of the progress by 1
                    $("#progressBar").progressbar("option", "value", progress + 1);
                }
                $("#completeCount").text(custRecordsRendered + "/" + totalRecords + " Records Rendered");
            }
              function displayCustomerInformation(ele) {
                $("#tblemp").append(ele);
            }
               ///Method to convertt the JSON data into an array
            function getDataInArray(array) {
                var cust = [];
                $.each(array, function (i, d) {
                    cust.push(d);
                });
                return cust;
            }


        });
```

I actually wanted to make my Browser UI not getting stucked when data is getting loaded. But Browser is having rendering issues when this much data get loads into the browser. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Virtualization, Pagination sort of things might help you

Comment: Can you please give some explanation

Comment: You can have a look at [Virtualizing/Paging Data in ObservableCollection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220774/virtualizing-paging-data-in-observablecollection-bound-to-itemscontrol-in-winrt) to get the idea how it works but it is no where related to your question.

Comment: Or you could install : [Grid.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grid.Mvc/)

Comment: Okay Let me try it. By the way, Thanks

Comment: And in addition install: [Grid.Mvc.Ajax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grid.Mvc.Ajax/) to ajaxy your grid. I installed and used it recently and it really did work nice and easy!

Comment: How could any user possibly absorb 1 million records in a view. [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)